# How to correctly use fontawsome with react-native

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome) to add fontawsome to my react-native project. I was Able to an Icon with the example from the link

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faCoffee } />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

How can I use other Icons? For example . I am not sure how would be the name of this icon. I tried fadFaHourglass but obviously dose not work.

Comment: `import { faCoffee } from '@fontawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'` may be a spell mistake

Answer (score 2):

Try with react-native-vector-icons

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const myIcon = <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;
```

User myIcon variable in your code.

Ref link:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons